# Bitbucket global hook or default configuration

Tags: git, hook, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I'm hosting an atlassian bitbucket server on my own dedicated machine and I need to send an HTTP-request to a remote-script containing at least the project- and repository name for each push to any of the repositories.

For now I've been trying the plugins `HTTP Request Post-Receive Hook for Stash` and `Bitbucket Server Web Post Hooks Plugin`. Basically it's working but the hook has to be configured for each repository which results in high maintenance and is too error prone (we've got many repos and there will be many more in the future)...

What I want is a "global" hook which fires for any repository, or if that's not possible something like a default-setting for one of the hook-plugins mentioned above to automatically apply to new repositores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't baked in currently. There's an open feature request you can watch and vote for [here](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-3597).

In the meantime, one thing you can do is use the REST API to apply hooks programatically. The hooks endpoint is documented [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/bitbucket-server/4.3.1/bitbucket-rest.html#idp3519536) and there are endpoints on the same page for iterating over projects and repositories.

Disclosure: I work for Atlassian

Comment: Hi. How does the situation look like now after more than half a decade?

Comment: It is unbelievable that 7 years later this functionality still does not exist in the cloud. Any workaround?